# Transfer calls to Bluetooth Speaker programmatically android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to connect to my device to a Bluetooth Speaker which supports A2DP and HFP.

I managed to get the device to connect to A2DP but on click of a button i want it to rout any calls to speaker and if i press the button again it should cancel that and all calls will be routed back to the phone.
For some reason it is not transferring the calls i tried different ways, here is the one i reached now

```
static PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if(DataHolder.SPEAKER_PHONE){

            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    am2.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_RINGTONE);
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                am2.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    am2.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
            }

        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
};

public static void transferCalls(){
 telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (telephonyManager != null) {
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
      am2.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
      am2.startBluetoothSco();
}

public static void stopTransferCalls(){
    am2.stopBluetoothSco();
    am2.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
    am2.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    am2.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    am2.abandonAudioFocus(new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Last time I checked, the built-in phone app already supported switching calls between BT, earpiece and loudspeaker.